# Ember Data expects a root element

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have this model:

```
App.Me = DS.Model.extend({
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    firstname: DS.attr('string'),
    lastname: DS.attr('string')
});
```

And i'm trying to fetch it, and my response looks like this: {"email":"iamanemail@gmail.com","firstname":"Mads","lastname":"Mylastname"}

Ember then says thw following in my console:

```
WARNING: Encountered "email" in payload, but no model was found for model name "email" (resolved model name using DS.RESTSerializer.typeForRoot("email")) ember-1.8.0.js:15358
WARNING: Encountered "firstname" in payload, but no model was found for model name "firstname" (resolved model name using DS.RESTSerializer.typeForRoot("firstname")) ember-1.8.0.js:15358
WARNING: Encountered "lastname" in payload, but no model was found for model name "lastname" (resolved model name using DS.RESTSerializer.typeForRoot("lastname")) ember-1.8.0.js:15358
Error: Assertion Failed: The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined
```

So i assume that it is because Ember expects a root object called "me", but how do i rewrite it?

EDIT: Now i got the correct format:

```
{"me":[{"email":"iamanemail@gmail.com","firstname":"Mads","lastname":"Mylastname"}]} main.js:33
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the serializer to fix the dataformat like so:

```
App.MeSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: 'email',
    extractArray: function (store, primaryType, payload) {
        var primaryTypeName = primaryType.typeKey;

        var typeName = primaryTypeName,
            type = store.modelFor(typeName);

        var data = {};
        var item = [];
        item.push(payload)
        data[typeName] = item;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        payload = data;

        return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain me why this error occured and how this fix is achieved?

Comment: It occured because Ember expects the data to follow a certain convention and therefore expected the JSON to have a root-element. This solution rewrites the JSON if it doesn't have a root-element.